# Symfony2 force twig to output XML formated data

Tags: php, xml, symfony, sitemap

I am using Symfony2 and struggling to use twig to output data in a XML format. Instead what happens twig just throws massive block of text on to the browser it is only when right click to view source i can see nicely laid out XML.

Is there any way I can force Twig to actually output formatted XML instead blok of text without having to view page source...?

sitemap.xml.twig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        {% for entry in sitemapresp %}
            <loc>{{ entry['url'] }}</loc>
            <lastmod>{{ entry['date'] }}</lastmod>
            <changefreq>{{ entry['frequency'] }}</changefreq>
            <priority>{{ entry['priority'] }}</priority>

        {% endfor %}
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Browser Output:

```
http://www.sitemappro.com/2015-01-27T23:55:42+01:00daily0.5http://www.sitemappro.com/download.html2015-01-26T17:24:27+01:00daily0.5
```

Source View Output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.90">
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.sitemappro.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-01-27T23:55:42+01:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
      </url>
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.sitemappro.com/download.html</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-01-26T17:24:27+01:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
      </url>
</urlset>
```

Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 13):

If you need the page to be XML, you will need to set the content type of the response.

```
$response = new Response($this->render('sitemap.xml.twig'));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');
return $response;
```

If you only want part of the page to render the code in an HTML page, use:

```
{% autoescape %}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        {% for entry in sitemapresp %}
            <loc>{{ entry['url'] }}</loc>
            <lastmod>{{ entry['date'] }}</lastmod>
            <changefreq>{{ entry['frequency'] }}</changefreq>
            <priority>{{ entry['priority'] }}</priority>

        {% endfor %}
    </url>
</urlset>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: by this solution before rendering I was getting " HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date:          Tue, 12 Jan 2016 13:10:25 GMT"

Comment: if you can elaborate what is autoescape and endautoescape ?

Comment: the same problem - returns HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache before content, but @smarber answer works fine

Comment: $response = $this->render('sitemap.xml.twig'); it's better render is response

Answer (score 10):

Controller side:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
return $this->render(
   'Bundle:Controller:sitemap.xml.twig',
   array(
        'param1' => $param1,// ...
   ),
   $response
);
```

Comment: this works for me, and did not return "HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date:          Tue, 12 Jan 2016 13:10:25 GMT
" before rendering.

Comment: "xml" is an invalid Content-Type, use application/xml or text/xml

Answer (score 2):

You must render only view in order to send it to response.

```
$response = new Response($this->renderView('sitemap.xml.twig'));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');
return $response;
```

So replace `$this->render(...)` with `$this->renderView(...)`

`HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache....` will disappear