# Symfony2 Save .twig output to web directory

Tags: symfony

I have a sitemap that is generated the same way as regular webpage(index, contacts, etc..).
Now I want to just run cron once a day/week and save sitemap.xml to /web directory.

Is it possible to save .twig template output **to /web directory of the website**?

Thanks

*PS: I'm planning to create symfony command to generate sitemap.xml to /web directory. But I'm not sure if it's gonna work.*

Comment: Have you seen [this so link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819660/symfony2-force-twig-to-output-xml-formated-data)? Then you could create a xml twig file...

Comment: Yes I saw it, this will save xml file to MY computer, I want to save this file to /web directory. That is my question.

Comment: Are you planning to use a cron job to call the template?

Comment: Yes I'm planning to use cronjob to generate sitemap file. 
I have been thinking about creating symfony command. But I'm not sure if it's gonna work.

Comment: I withdrew my answer because @PatrikKarisch 's answer seems like the best solution for you to use.

Comment: It could stay dynamic so you don't have to run a cron, it would be always up to date and witjout sitemap.xml file in tge `/web/` directory.

Comment: I have 20000+ records in DB, so better just generate new file once a week then every time for X robots/people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Simply create a command which generates your sitemap.xml. It doesn't matter if you render the sitemap with twig or php xml functions. You simply save it with php. So this may be in your command:

```
$sitemap = // however you collect the sites

$renderedSitemap = $this->getContainer()->get('templating')
    ->render('sitemap/sitemap.xml.twig', [
        'sitemap' => $sitemap,
    ]);

file_put_contents(
    dirname($this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.root_dir')).'/web/sitemap.xml',
    $renderedSitemap
);
```

That's all. Your command must extend `ContainerAwareCommand` to have access to the container. And the constructed path expects the standard symfony structure. If you have changed that, you must adapt the path.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. 
I think you've forgotten to put $renderedSitemap to file_put_contents as $data parameter.